# Javascript call function after another function executes

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Below are my three functions. I am calling function 1 & 2 in 3 but I am getting an error. My text is not showing inside my canvas. Only the image is getting displayed. How can I make the functions delay the text function until `make_base` finishes loading.

**Function 1**

```
function make_base(img) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = img;
    base_image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

**Function 2**

```
function text(text) {
    context.fillText(text, 50, 50)
}
```

**Function 3**

```
function render() {
    make_base(xxx)
    text(xxx)
}
```

I have used setTimeout doesnt work because sometimes make_base takes little time to load.

Comment: so use a promise so you know when it is done. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well since it is an asynchronous task, you need to add logic to tell the next code when to run. Classic way is to use a a callback method:

```
function make_base(img, callback) {
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = img;
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
    callback()
  }
}

function text(text) {
  context.fillText(text, 50, 50)
}

function render() {
  make_base(xxx, function () {
    text(xxx)
  })
}
```

or move into modern patterns is to use a promise

```
function make_base(img) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = img;
    base_image.onload = function(){
      context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
      resolve()
    }
}

function text(text) {
  context.fillText(text, 50, 50)
}

function render() {
  make_base(xxx).then(function () {
    text(xxx)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `text()` function inside of `make_base()` onload function so the `text()` function loads after the `make_base()` function has finished loading all of its variable declarations like this:

```
function text(text) {
    context.fillText(text, 50, 50)
}

function make_base(img) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'https://davidwalsh.name/demo/ringo-ftw.jpg';
    base_image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
        text(text);
    }
}

function render() {
    make_base(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`make_base` is performing an asynchronous operation and adding a callback for when that operation completes:

```
base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
}
```

If you want your `text` function to be called after that callback, put it in the callback function:

```
function make_base(img) {
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = img;
    base_image.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
        text();
    }
}

//...

function render() {
    make_base(xxx);
}
```